# Why is my code returning the answer a million times?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

[image: csvfile]

I have a few different functions im figuring out based on some data in csv file. When I run the program, it returns the answer like a million times and I only need it once. ALSO, for my second function, how do I get my function to return a certain index[] from the same row based on user input. so they give me a location within the file, how do I get it to return row[-5] based on that location.

```
import csv

def coldest_temperature(input_file):
    file = open("weather.csv","r")
    file.readline()
    smallest_so_far = 0
    location = ""
    date = ""

    for each_line in file:
        each_line = each_line.replace('"',"")
        row = each_line.split(",")

        if int(row[-3]) < smallest_so_far:
            smallest_so_far = int(row[-3])
            location = row[7]
            date = row[1]
        print("Coldest Fahrenheit temperature reading: ", smallest_so_far)
        print("Location: ", location)
        print("Date: ", date)

def average_temperature(input_file, location):
    file = open("weather.csv","r")
    file.readline()
    s = 0

    for each_line in file:
        each_line = each_line.replace('"',"")
        row = each_line.split(",")
        if location == row[-7]:
            print(row[-5])
        print(location)

def all_stations_by_state(input_file, state):
    file = open("weather.csv","r")
    file.readline()

    for each_line in file:
        each_line = each_line.replace('"',"")
        row = each_line.split(",")

def menu():
    print()
    print("1. Identify coldest temperature.")
    print("2. Identify average temperature for a given location.")
    print("3. Identify all recording station locations by state.")
    print("4. Something interesting, non-trivial and not a variation of the above options.")
print("5. Quit.")
print()



def main():
    input_file = "weather.csv"
    choice = 0
    while (choice != 5):
        menu()
        choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
        print()
        if (choice == 1):
            coldest_temperature(input_file)
        elif (choice == 2):
            location = input("Enter desired location (e.g. Miles City, MT): ")
            average_temperature(input_file, location)
        elif (choice == 3):
            state = input("Enter name of state (e.g. Montana): ")
            all_stations_by_state(input_file, state)
        elif (choice == 4):
            pass
        elif (choice != 5):
            print("That is not a valid option.  Please try again.")
    print("Goodbye!")
```

## -----------------------------------------+

```
main()
```

Comment: PLease format your code properly and show sample csv file

Comment: Hard to say without correct indentation in your question, or your actual CSV file, but I'd strongly recommend using pandas if you want to do CSV analysis

Comment: If you want to print once, don't put the print functions inside a for loop.

Comment: If you want to only print out the min or average _once_, it needs to be ***outside*** of any loop. Or if you did use pandas, you wouldn't need any loop

Comment: Images of data, and especially a link to an image of data, are not helpful.  Paste the text of the CSV flie in the question so it can be used to run the code.  Also, this code is only functions.  Provide a [mcve] that runs the functions and demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Also, don't manually split csv lines, or replace quotes... Especially weather which can include city/state with commas within a single column. You imported the CSV module, so you should use it